# FBconnect jar download

Tags: android, facebook, fbconnect

Bit of tricky but am developing fbconnect application using [fbconnect blog](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/tag/android-facebook-tutorial/)  but i cannot find that fbconnect.jar !! Can I know where i can download that..and fix that

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to the source is still there, you can build the jar using that http://code.google.com.iproxy.saverpigeeks.com/p/fbconnect-android/downloads/detail?name=fbconnect-android.zip&can=2&q=

However, I do recommend you using the  facebook android SDK to integrate facebook to your app. You can find the URL here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

and the usage here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android